# Search for every blank line in document, and pop first line after that?

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is go through a document line by line, find each blank line, keep traversing until I hit the next line of text, and pop that line.
So for example, what I want to do is this:

> Paragraph 1
>   This is a line.
>   This is another line.
>
> Here is a line after a space, which I want to pop!
>   Here is the next line, which I want to keep.
>
> Here is another line I want to pop.

So it will go through each number of blank lines until it hits the next sentence, and pops that sentence only, then continues on. I am thinking I should use re.split('\n') , but I am not sure.
I am sorry I have no code to post but I really don't know where to start
any help would be much appreciated, thank you!
this is part of a larger code, which i've worked days and days on and have figured out up to this point, so I have done the bulk of the word.

Comment: What makes you think you should use `re.split` if you're just splitting on a fixed literal string? Just doing `s.split('\n')` does exactly the same thing as `re.split('\n', s)`, and it's simpler. (Still, +1 for structuring the question as "Here's what I want to do, and here's what I tried but couldn't make work" instead of "How do I make this thing I tried work for some unspecified problem", as so many do.)

Comment: While I understand you are a `Python Newbie` as your title says, this can also easily be accomplished from a command line with `grep -P -A 1 -m 1 "^$" test2.py | grep -P ".+"`

Comment: What does "pop" mean? Do you want to print all lines except "popped"?

Answer (score 1):

If you do `for line in filehandle:` it will iterate over each line. If you have a flag that is true when the previous line is blank you can skip the next line then reset the flag.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the original poster (OP) wants to remove those lines in-place, meaning removing those lines from the file. Here is a revised solution (my previous solution was off the mark. Thank you J.F Sebastian for telling me.

```
import fileinput

def remove_line_after_blank(filename, in_place_edit=False):
    previous_line = ''
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=in_place_edit):
        if not (previous_line == '\n' and line != '\n'):
            print line.rstrip()
        previous_line = line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_line_after_blank('data.txt', in_place_edit=True)
```

#### Discussion

- If you do not want to modify the original data file, remove `, in_place_edit=True`.

Comment: I think the OP wants the opposite: print all lines excepted "popped".

Comment: "I think" means I'm not certain. Keep also the first solution, just in case. See also [comments under @abarnert's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421424/search-for-every-blank-line-in-document-and-pop-first-line-after-that/15421519?noredirect=1#comment21808795_15421541).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest novice solution by far is probably the way Steve suggested: Just iterate the lines, and use a flag to keep track of whether the last line was a blank line.

But if you want a higher-level solution, you need to rethink the problem at a higher level. What you're actually trying to specify is the first line of every paragraph but the first, where "paragraphs" are things divided by empty lines. Right?

So, how could you do that? Well, you can split on `'\n\n'` just as easily as on `\n`. So:

```
paragraphs = document.split('\n\n')
first_lines = [paragraph.partition('\n')[0] for paragraph in paragraphs]
popped_lines = first_lines[1:]
```

(I used `partition` instead of `split` here both because it splits only at the first `'\n'`, leaving the rest alone, and because it handles one-line paragraphs right—which `paragraph.split('\n', 1)` would not.)

But you don't want a list of the popped lines, you want a list of everything *but* the popped lines, right?

```
paragraphs = document.split('\n\n')
first, rest = paragraphs[0], paragraphs[1:]
rest_edited = [paragraph.partition('\n')[1] for paragraph in rest]
```

And if you want to turn that back into a document:

```
all_edited = [first] + rest_edited
document_edited = '\n\n'.join(all_edited)
```

You can shorten that a bit by using slice assignment, although I'm not sure it's quite as readable:

```
paragraphs = document.split('\n\n')
paragraphs[1:] = [paragraph.partition('\n')[1] for paragraph in paragraphs[1:]]
document_edited = '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)
```

---

As J.F. Sebastian points out, the question is a little ambiguous. Does "blank lines" mean "empty lines", or "lines with nothing but whitespace in them"? If it's the latter, things are a bit more complicated, and the easiest solution probably *is* a simple regex (`r'\n\s*\n'`) for the splitting into paragraphs.

---

Meanwhile, if what you have is a sequence of lines (and note that a file is a sequence of lines!) rather than one big string, you can do this without split at all, in a few different ways.

For example, paragraphs are groups of non-blank lines, right? So you can use the `groupby` function to get them:

```
groups = itertools.groupby(lines, bool)
```

Or, if "blank" doesn't mean "empty":

```
groups = itertools.groupby(lines, lambda line: not line.strip())
```

Note that this gives you `(False, <sequence of lines>)` for each paragraph, and `(True, <sequence of blank lines>)` for each blank line. If you want to preserve blank lines as-is, you can—but if you're happy just replacing each run of blank lines with a single empty line (which you obviously are if "blank" *does* mean "empty"), it's probably easier to throw away the blank paragraphs:

```
paragraphs = (group for (key, group) in paragraphs if not key)
```

Then you can remove the first element from all but the first group, and finally chain the groups back together into one big sequence:

```
first = next(paragraphs)
edited_paragraphs = (itertools.islice(paragraph, 1) for paragraph in paragraphs)
edited_document = itertools.chain(first, *edited_paragraphs)
```

---

Finally, what if you have runs of multiple blank lines in a row? Well, first you have to decide how to deal with them. If you have two blank lines, do you remove the second? If so, do you remove the first line of the next paragraph (because it was originally after a blank line), or not (because the blank line it was after was already removed)? What if you have three in a row? Splitting on `'\n\n'` will do one thing, splitting on `'\n\s*\n'` a different thing, and `groupby` yet another… but until you know what you want, it's impossible to say which is "right" or how to "fix" the others, of course.

Comment: Is "blank" the same as "empty"? "\n\n" works only for empty lines.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Well, he didn't define what he means by "blank lines", but it seems like the most likely meaning. (It's the one most of the other answers have assumed, and it's also what you expect if someone says he's thinking of splitting on newlines without mentioning stripping.) But you're right, it's worth clarifying that.

Comment: Note: `\n\s*\n` can match *multiple* blank lines but `\n\n` finds a *single* empty line.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, and it's not clear how he wants to deal with runs of blank lines at all. Since it doesn't come up in his sample input, it was simpler to assume it doesn't matter, and my answer is already long enough… but it's definitely worth pointing out in a comment.

Comment: "find each blank line, keep traversing until I hit the next line of text" seems clear that *multiple* blank lines are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

use `re.findall` to match all occurrence in a string:

```
>>> text = """Paragraph 1
This is a line.
This is another line.

Here is a line after a space, which I want to pop!
Here is the next line, which I want to keep.

Here is another line I want to pop."""
>>> re.findall("\n\n+(.+)", text)
['Here is a line after a space, which I want to pop!', 'Here is another line I want to pop.']
>>> re.findall("\n\n+(.+)$", text, re.MULTILINE)
['Here is a line after a space, which I want to pop!', 'Here is another line I want to pop.']
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to split the text on newlines:

```
lines = your_string.split("\n")
```

That would break it up into an array (stored in `lines`), where each element of the array is a separate line of text. (As noted in the comments, if you have a file object already, you can just loop through that.)

Then you could go through each line of `lines`, checking for a newline. If you find one, you could "pop" out the next one. (I don't know what you mean by pop, so I just have the code printing out the lines you want.)

```
for line in lines:
  if print_next_line:
     print(line)
     print_next_line = False

  if line == "":
    print_next_line = True
```

Comment: If his document is a file, it's easier to not `split` at all, because a file is already a sequence of lines…

Comment: `if line == "\n"` is pointless since string is already split by `\n`

Comment: @abarnert: that's true, but from my read of the original post I wasn't sure if it was a file or just an inline string.

Comment: @thedayturns: I'm not sure either. I was just adding that as a comment, in case it _is_ a file.